# Link from my app to iTunes - connection error?

Tags: xcode, hyperlink, itunes

I am trying to create a button in my app to take users to another app in the iTunes store. I am just using NSURL and I have copied the link from iTunes replacing the 'itunes' part to 'phobos'. When I click the button it opens the app store but I get an error saying "cannot connect to itunes store". I can connect if I just go to the app store on my phone so I guess this means I am doing something wrong in my app rather than there actually being a connection problem. Any ideas?

This is my code

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms://phobos.apple.com/gb/app/pastatime/id335197364?mt=8";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]
         ];
```

This is the link I copy from iTunes http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/pastatime/id335197364?mt=8

Comment: I just realised this is not opening the AppStore app on my phone but the iTunes app which is causing the problem, any more ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Use the `itms://` protocol handler.

Comment: That didn't help. I am trying to connect to the UK store does that make a difference? This is the link I copy from iTunes itunes.apple.com/gb/app/pastatime/id335197364?mt=8 and this is what I have changed it to itms://phobos.apple.com/gb/app/pastatime/id335197364?mt=8 Any more ideas?